# MYSQL Last Entry in a GROUP BY from m to n JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Hy guys , 
a read about 20 question but i still have a problem 
cause it looks all different or i simple not see what solution 
is working on my problem .

I Want to write to all my customer , they move on every year to another flat 
i did a table users and a table address and a mton to join them .
But when a user have 2 address i get always the first address with group by 
or both address when join them without group by .

could someone show me the answer , i bet there is already a solution i missing

shortcut of my tables

```
CREATE DATABASE DL;

CREATE TABLE DL.users (
  uidx int PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  email varchar(255) 
);
INSERT INTO DL.users VALUES (NULL,'myemail'),(NULL,'heremail');
CREATE TABLE DL.address (
  aidx int PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  address varchar(255) 
);
INSERT INTO DL.address VALUES (NULL,'myadress'),(NULL,'heraddress');
CREATE TABLE DL.ntom (
  nidx int PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  fk_uidx int ,
  fk_aidx int ,
  movein date
);
INSERT INTO DL.ntom VALUES (NULL,1,1,'2016-01-01'),(NULL,2,2,'2016-01-01'),(NULL,1,2,'2017-01-01');
```

now it gives me

```
SELECT email,address,movein FROM DL.users 
JOIN DL.ntom ON uidx = fk_uidx
JOIN DL.address ON aidx = fk_aidx

myemail    myadress     2016-01-01
heremail   heraddress   2016-01-01
myemail    heraddress   2017-01-01
```

when i group by and Order by the date 
myemail still live at myadress and not at heraddress

```
SELECT email,address,movein FROM DL.users 
JOIN DL.ntom ON uidx = fk_uidx
JOIN DL.address ON aidx = fk_aidx
GROUP BY DL.users.email ORDER BY DL.ntom.movein desc

myemail    myadress     2016-01-01
heremail   heraddress   2016-01-01
```

please help me , he wanna move in to her place , he loves her so mutch

expected result :

```
myemail    heraddress   2017-01-01
heremail   heraddress   2016-01-01
```

:) <3

Thanks .

Comment: why you are using group by ? you are not using any aggregation function ...and please show us the expected  result

Comment: I am trying to understand what exactly you are trying to ask. Can you clarify more.

Comment: Does this `SELECT email,address,movein FROM DL.users  JOIN DL.ntom ON uidx = fk_uidx JOIN DL.address ON aidx = fk_aidx WHERE fk_uidx != fk_aidx  ORDER BY DL.ntom.movein desc;` give you expected result? Really hard to understand what result you want to get)

Comment: i want 
myemail    heraddress   2017-01-01
heremail   heraddress   2016-01-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
SELECT email,address,movein FROM DL.users u 
JOIN (SELECT fk_uidx,max(movein) as maxmovein from DL.ntom group by fk_uidx) as t ON u.uidx = t.fk_uidx
JOIN DL.ntom t2 on t2.fk_uidx=t.fk_uidx and t2.movein=t.maxmovein
JOIN DL.address a ON a.aidx = fk_aidx
ORDER BY t2.movein desc
```

Comment: perfect , thanks .  now i try to understand the simple subselect step :)

Comment: oh sorry , i think i missed that step